# Qt Stylesheet for QMessageBox

Tags: qt, qt4, stylesheet

I am using stylesheets. I want to set style information for the main message text and the informative text for a QMessageBox. Is it possible to access these sub-controls ?

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is possible. The trick is to know how to select the sub-controls. Here's how you can change the style of the text, in this example I make the dialog grey and the text off-white:

```
QMessageBox {
    background-color: #333333;
}

QMessageBox QLabel {
    color: #aaa;
}
```

The second clause uses a `Descendant Selector` which in this case means "any QLabel that is a descendant of a QMessageBox including children and grandchildren etc". You can be more specific and only select children with `QMessageBox > QLabel`

I found this information here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use rich text - with the exception for the detailed text since it's always interpreted as plain text.

Take a look at the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmessagebox.html#rich-text-and-the-text-format-property).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `QMessageBox {font:...}` in the stylesheet or with setStyleSheet(...)

Unless you trying to set the style for the main message text separately from the informative text... is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to set the style for the main message text separately from the informative text.

Comment: In that case, I would advise taking a look at this website:  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qitemdelegate.html#

Comment: Since QMessageBox has nothing to do with model/view then how would this be relevant ? Maybe you can suggest a way to use it; I don't see how.

Comment: I am having troubles remembering exactly where I was going when I referenced that website, but I am almost certain there was a point to it.  If all else fails, would making a custom QMessageBox be a possibility?  That way you could actually control the specifics of what is being painted by overriding the paint methods.  Sorry I can't provide real sample code and more specific advise (I am quite busy and my mind is drifting too much as it is).

Comment: I could make a custom styled message box clone but that defeats the point of using a standard widget and stylesheets...

Comment: Ah ok.  Well here is what I would suggest.  Make your instance of the QMessageBox and setInformationText() and what not.  Then do a print out of the findChildren() method that you call on the instance of the QMessageBox you just made.  It will give you a long string of the list of objects inside the QMessageBox, along with some of their object names.  For example, the object of the label containing the informativeText (I assume) is the QLabel with the name "qt_msgbox_informativelabel".  You could change the stylesheets using these object names to set each one on their own.  Does that help?

Comment: Currently, no. If I follow your suggestion I may get to an answer. I haven't tested it yet and the child widgets may not have been given object names. I'm not sure that I want to use your answer because it's not standard, I'm not looking for an answer that could break between point releases of Qt.